# Is there a plural form of pneuma in the Greek manuscripts of the Bible?

Tags: greek, translation-philosophy, spirit, spirits

Thanks so far.....however I am specifically asking if there are two different forms found in the ancient greek manuscripts. Strongs only references 4151 for singular and plural. Where might I find explanation of how translaters differentiated between a spirit and multiple spirits?   In Hebrews 12:9 the Greek word translated in English, Spirits, is pneuma. (strongs 4151)
In the Greek manuscripts of the Bible is there a word or form of word to designate a singular "pnuema" and a different word or form to designate "pnuemas" (sic) or does context determine the translations using the singular or plural form in English?

Comment: should have first searched duckduckgo and biblehub to check the interlinear and words https://biblehub.com/greek/4151.htm

Comment: The seven spirits of God are mentioned in Revelation 1:4. Πνευμάτων is gentive neuter plural [see Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/revelation/1-4.htm). Otherwise, the word is singular. There is never any ambiguity about context.

Comment: Michael16, thanks I forgot about that site. The link msays the sense is determined by context, however NigelJ and Dotard seem to imply that there is another word form that strongs leaves out. Which is accurate and where can I find a deeper explaination?

Answer (score 1):

The plural form "spirits" πνεύματα (pneumata) occurs in a few places such as:

- Matt 12:45
- Mark 1:27
- Mark 3:11
- Mark 5:13
- Luke 7:21
- Luke 10:20
- Luke 11:26
- etc

In the particular case of Heb 12:9 the grammatical form is πνευμάτων = genitive neuter plural.  If this were genitive neuter singular, the form would be (as per Matt 1:18)     πνεύματος.

Comment: Thanks so far.....however I am specifically asking if there are two different forms found in the ancient greek manuscripts. Strongs only references 4151 for singular and plural references to what is translated in English as Plural. Further the link from Michael16 biblehub.com/greek/4151.htm says that context determins the sense. Which is the correct view? Where might I find explanation of how translaters differentiated between a spirit and multiple spirits?

Comment: The above comments all refer to the Greek and NOT the English.  Strongs lists the lexical form.  In the Greek we have Genitive, Dative, Nominative, accusative, as well as both singular and plural.  I have given specific instances listed above as they occur in the manuscripts and faithfully transcribed to our modern Greek New Testaments.

Comment: thanks Dottard  which concordance/dictionary/interlinear might I find this explained?

Comment: @ACME - see https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/1-18.htm and https://biblehub.com/greek/4151.htm  and  https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_4151.htm

Comment: thanks,  so the plural for can be used as a form only and wether the writer used it to describe more than one is for the interpretor to use context to translate the word with correct sense into english, I assume.

Comment: @ACME - plural "spirits" means, as usual, more than one, ie, many.  Nothing complicated about that.

Comment: In mt 1:18 is plural form but singular spirit, apparantly more complicated than you think.....

Comment: @ACME - the Greek is πνεύματος which is definitely SINGULAR.